# Display the values in calender from list

Tags: java, jsp, date, jstl

Hiii.
I have a set of values  like `[11-07-2014,present,lateby10min]` in `listobject`
I would like to display values(present,lateby10min)  in calender by compare dates present  in list with calender dates..
is it possible?
suppose iam getting all the values in jsp by **"${alist}"** from this i have seprated "date" by "${alist.date}" how can i compare this date with calender date and how can i display the values present in list?..is it possible can any one help me..

```
<c:forEach items="${alist}" var="list" varStatus="status">
Date : ${list.date}
attendance :${list.attendance}
remarks    : ${list.remarks}
<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Please explain better

Answer (score 1):

First thing - you need to have a `Day` objects in the list if you want to access its properties like `${day.date}`

```
<c:forEach items="${alist}" var="day" varStatus="status">
Date : ${day.date}
attendance :${day.attendance}
remarks    : ${day.remarks}
<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Secondly, you should have a code ready to display calendar on your JSP.

Then you can go iterate through all days and compare with calendar dates, and then mark remarks as per other two properties of day (attendance and remarks).